# Pass Default Application Context to Remote EJB Anonymously

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, ejb-3.1, wildfly-8

I have a complicated scenario, for which i have no idea how to go about:

I have my ejbs running in a remote server.

And my web application running in a different server.

I have an ApplicationContext, that will differ based on domain, language, country etc.

I would like this application context to be passed to the remote EJB anonymously, in such a way that developers dont have to invoke all of their backend requests with the ApplicationContext as a parameter.

This is the scenarion, lets says i have a remote Stateless EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class MyStateless implements MyStatelessRemote{

  //The application context that needs to be supplied form the front-end
  @Inject //probably define a producer method to always supply a new one.
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  public void doCheckSomething(final MySomethingData data){}

}
```

And on the frontend:

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class MyController implements Serializable{

  @EJB
  private MyStatelessRemote statelessRemote
  //The current application/session context to be passed to the Stateless ejb on every invocation.
  @Inject
  private ApplicationContext executionContext;

  public void doSomeOrderOrSomethingSimilar(){
    //At this point, the current application context needs to be supplied to the remote EJB
    //Which it may use to check on order validity based on configurations such as country
    //language etc.
    statelessRemote.doCheckSomething(mySomething);
  }
}
```

With more than 20 EJBS and each having an average of 8 to 10 methods, and considering the likelihood that almost every ejb may need to know the executioncontext of the caller,
is it possible to parse the current execution context, through configuration or otherwise to the ejb during invocation of any method?

1. I am using Wildfly8 with remote ejb3.1, CDI1.1, JSF2.2
2. The application context may change when, for example the user changes his/her language

EDIT:

I am looking for something similar to Web Service inbound and outbound interceptors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few months working on jboss/wildfly server, i finally found a away to achieve this functionality:

Client-Side Code: (Based on jboss ejbclient)

```
package com.mycompany.view.service.wildfly.invocationcontext;

import com.mycompany.ejb.internal.MyCompanyAccount;
import com.mycompany.view.service.account.LoggedInAccount;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.jboss.ejb.client.AttachmentKey;
import org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext;
import org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInterceptor;
import org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext;

import static com.mycompany.management.wildfly.invocationcontext.MyCompanyInvocationContextKey.MYCOMPANY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER;

/**
 * Registers itself as a jboss client interceptor.
 * @author marembo
 */
@Singleton
@Startup
public class MyCompanyInvocationContextInterceptor implements EJBClientInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyCompanyInvocationContextInterceptor.class.getName());
    private static final AttachmentKey<Long> MYCOMPANY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_KEY = new AttachmentKey<>();

    @Inject
    @LoggedInAccount
    private Instance<MyCompanyAccount> loggedInAccount;

    @PostConstruct
    void registerSelf() {
        EJBClientContext.requireCurrent().registerInterceptor(0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleInvocation(final EJBClientInvocationContext ejbcic) throws Exception {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Intercepting invocation on: {0}", ejbcic.getInvokedMethod());

        final EJBClientContext clientContext = ejbcic.getClientContext();
        if (!loggedInAccount.isUnsatisfied()) {
            final MyCompanyAccount mycompanyAccount = loggedInAccount.get();
            if (mycompanyAccount != null) {
                final Long accountNumber = mycompanyAccount.getAccountNumber();
                clientContext.putAttachment(MYCOMPANY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_KEY, accountNumber);
            }
        }
        ejbcic.getContextData().put(MYCOMPANY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, "348347878483");

        ejbcic.sendRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleInvocationResult(final EJBClientInvocationContext ejbcic) throws Exception {
        return ejbcic.getResult();
    }

}
```

On the server side, i register a global interceptor:

```
package com.mycompany.management.wildfly.extension;

import com.mycompany.management.facade.account.MyCompanyAccountFacade;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.EJBContext;
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

/**
 * Default interceptor does not require @Interceptor
 * @author marembo
 */
public class MyCompanyInvocationContextReceiver {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyCompanyInvocationContextReceiver.class.getName());

    @Resource
    private EJBContext ejbContext;
    @EJB
    private MyCompanyInvocationContext mycompanyInvocationContext;
    @EJB
    private MyCompanyAccountFacade mycompanyAccountFacade;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object setMyCompanyAccount(final InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {
        final Map<String, Object> contextData = ejbContext.getContextData();
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "EJBContext data: {0}", contextData);
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "InvocationContext data: {0}", invocationContext.getContextData());

        return invocationContext.proceed();
    }
}
```

and the ejb-jar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         version = "3.1"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor>
            <interceptor-class>com.mycompany.management.wildfly.extension.MyCompanyInvocationContextReceiver</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>

    <assembly-descriptor>
        <interceptor-binding>
            <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
            <interceptor-class>com.mycompany.management.wildfly.extension.MyCompanyInvocationContextReceiver</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor-binding>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

As indicated on the server side interceptor, you can get the client-sent-data either from the InvocationContext or from the EJBContext.

Comment: Anything you do here is container specific.

Comment: And you're doing exactly what I mentioned - passing parameters to your remote EJB (in this case, it's via an interceptor)

Comment: when you say passing parameters, the meaning i get is that i have an ejb method that accepts parameters i want to pass to them, but i here, i am sending additional data, using the ejbcontext, so unless you were clear on how to pass the parameter, i would understand, but i simply got the meaning of method parameters, anyone would.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is not possible using CDI/EJB, without passing in parameters to your remote EJB.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated answer. I have also done research and i know now you can do this based on CORBA IIOP on glassfish.