# Get EJB calling module

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

In my application I need to obtain the module name who called an EJB.
For example I have Ejb_A that calls Ejb_B, EJB_A belongs to module A and EJB_B to module B. I would like to obtain in someway in Ejb_B that the caller is A.
I googled but I didn't find much more usefull information.

I'm using Jboss eap 7, j2ee7.

Comment: Since you are on jboss/wildfly, you can see how i handled this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247689/pass-default-application-context-to-remote-ejb-anonymously

Answer (score 0):

If the caller is remote, that might be hard to do. Even if the two are deployed on the same app server if you look at the StackTrace for the current thread you'll only be able to step back as far as when the current worker thread received the incoming call, and you probably won't be able to step back any further than that to see who the caller was.

You could make it easier for yourself and pass a parameter that's some unique identifier String that identifies who the caller is. If it's critical for your app to know this info, I would look at something like this and build it into your API.

Comment: Sadly the caller is remote. I tried to use an interceptor and add a parameter in the session context, but it is null if read within the EJB. I cannot add a parameter to the method called because this would be change tons of methods signature. So I need to retrieve it automatically.

Comment: Since you are on jboss/wildfly, you can see how i handled this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247689/pass-default-application-context-to-remote-ejb-anonymously

Comment: I tried this solution, but the ejb itself cannot access to the parameters in the context data. If I include in the ejb  @Resource SessionContext and I invoke getContextData().get("myParameter") I get null, while it is available in the two interceptor.